# Flask Error: cannot create weak reference to 'LocalProxy' object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm following [Define and Access the Database](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tutorial/database/) tutorial, however I'm trying to setup Postgres instead of sqlite.

I have the following requirements:

```
Flask==3.0.2
Flask-Migrate==4.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.1.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
SQLAlchemy==2.0.27
```

My `db.py` is the following:

```
from flask import current_app, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
import click

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=Base)
        db.init_app(current_app)

        migrate = Migrate(current_app, db)
        g.db = db
        
    return g.db

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

@click.command('init-db')
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

But when I run the `flask --app flaskr init-db` command I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/src/app/flaskr/db.py", line 13, in get_db
    db.init_app(current_app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 359, in init_app
    engines = self._app_engines.setdefault(app, {})
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 508, in setdefault
    return self.data.setdefault(ref(key, self._remove),default)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'LocalProxy' object
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

It works when I tried it in a single file flask app.

Comment: Perhaps try the flask-sqlalchemy tutorial instead https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/quickstart/